# Geocoder Client side vs server side

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have one application in which there is a way to import address locations in to the system. This can be 10000 at a time.

Now after import, there is one tab for maps using which they can see their imported locations in to the map with marker.
For this i used geocoder because i don't have the lat and lng for each location.But while in Map i am getting the geocoder query limit error.

I did search and found that there is a limit of 10 per request and 2500 per day in geocoder api. Now i am cofused that 
1. If i use client side geocoder then in case of 3000 records to show on map at a time then how can i do that.
2. I found that we can do that using server side geocoder but that too has the limit of 2500 so what if some one is importing  10k records.

Please suggest me which method i should use.

And also need some more info about the limits too because i will have multiple users who will do the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that the client side geocoder of Maps JavaScript API wasn't designed for batch geocoding. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) highlight this fact:

> **Note**: Service requests are rate-limited per user session, regardless of how many users share the same project. When you first load the service API, you are allocated an initial quota of requests. Once you use this quota, the API enforces rate limits on additional requests on a per-second basis. If too many requests are made within a certain time period, the API returns an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response code. The per-session rate limit prevents the use of client-side services for batch requests. For batch requests, use the Maps API web services.

So if you need to geocode thousands of addresses the only available option is server side geocoding.

Server side geocoding has a 50 queries per second limit and 2500 daily requests by default.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

You can get more than 2500 daily requests if you enable Billing in your project. With Billing you can execute up to 100K daily requests with a price $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests.